# An error while building a game with PGS4A

Tags: android, python, pygame

I making a small game in python with pygame.
I wanted to make the game available for android.
Hopefully, there was PGS4A for this

After doing the configuration I had to build it.
So I just typed the command:

```
python android.py build ~/project/programming/python/gameEngine release install
```

And I ended up  with this error:

```
  BUILD FAILED
/home/turquoisepotato/project/programming/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:570: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/turquoisepotato/project/programming/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:622: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/turquoisepotato/project/programming/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:658: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/turquoisepotato/project/programming/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt" (in directory "/home/turquoisepotato/project/programming/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_licensing/library"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

What do I do with this. I'm lost.
I'm using crunch bang linux 11.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a 64-bit OS, while the binaries are compiled against 32-bit libraries.

I'm not familiar with CrunchBang's repositories, but you can probably try

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 lib32ncurses5
```

and then run the installer again.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this is a common problem that usually occurs on Windows with pgs4a 0.9.6.

Take a look at [this](http://pychildren.blogspot.com/2014/05/windows-81-and-pygame-subset-for.html).

To make sure that the directory structure of the unzipped file is the same as the screenshot.

You do not have a full android-sdk installed.  You need the missing files that the error refers to.  You can either roll-back to pgs4a 0.9.4, which doesn't use those licensing files or reinstall android-sdk

```
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6$ cd android-sdk/
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk$ ls
add-ons  extras  platforms  platform-tools  SDK Readme.txt  temp  tools
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk$ cd extras/
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras$ ls
google
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras$ cd google/
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google$ ls
play_apk_expansion  play_licensing
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google$ cd play_licensing/
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_licensing$ ls
library  LICENSE.txt  README.txt  sample  source.properties  test
craig@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_licensing$
```

This link may help.
http://discussion.pychildren.org/t/windows-installation/10

Answer (score 0):

To fix it go to this site http://ady.my/viewer/ and, in the section build, download the most recent version of build-tools. Extract the files 'aapt' and 'dx' and the directory 'lib' and move these all for the especified folder on the terminal /home/turquoisepotato/project/programming/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/platform-tools.

The code will be similar with this below:

```
mv aapt dx lib /home/turquoisepotato/project/programming/python/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/platform-tools
```

But the PGS4A is obselete. I suggest for you, use the Python for Android, that you find in this link: http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/